# One and two hop citation in scala

Tags: scala, spark-graphx

I have a list of "from node" and "to node" that looks like this:

```
1234        4567
1234        6789
1234        3456
4567        9876
….
```

The point is to find which node is the most significant, which means which has the most one and two hop citation: 1234 with (4567,6789,3456,9876 (because it is connected to 4567))

Currently all I did was a map and reduce function to get the most appearing node which would cover a single node citation. But I need to cover in cases where A -> B  and B -> C therefor A -> C.

current code to find top ten nodes:

```
val textFile = sc.textFile("cit-Patents.txt")

val arrayForm = textFile.filter(_.charAt(0)!='#')

val mapreduce = arrayForm.flatMap(line => line.split("\\s+")).map(word => (word,1)).reduceByKey(_ + _).sortBy(_._2,ascending=false).take(10);
```

I know graphX can help with this as well but I did not know how to do that.

If you need more information please let me know.
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think for your conditions you don't need spark-graphx. Your problem simply solved by joining your base `DataFrame` to itself, look at code:

suppose we have DataFrame with direct links from X to Y:

```
val df = Seq(
  (1234, 4567),
  (1234, 6789),
  (1234, 3456),
  (4567, 9876),
  (5, 6),
  (6, 7),
  (6, 8),
  (6, 9),
  (5, 9),
  (6, 10)
).toDF("X", "Y")
```

we see, what some rows has same `Y` value as another rows `X` value, it means we can do join DataFrame to itself (let's use `a` and `b` aliases) by condition: `a.Y` should be equal `b.X`:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
val twoHopCitation = df.as("a").join(
  df.as("b"), 
  col("a.Y") === col("b.X")
)
  .select(col("a.X").as("X"), col("b.Y").as("Y"))
```

now we see all transitive links from `a.X` to `b.Y`:

```
twoHopCitation.show()
+----+----+
|   X|   Y|
+----+----+
|1234|9876|
|   5|  10|
|   5|   9|
|   5|   8|
|   5|   7|
+----+----+
```

so, all what we need is union this two DataFrames, and aggregate by `X` counting `Y` and sort by `count Y` descending:

```
df.union(
  twoHopCitation
)
  .groupBy("X")
  .agg(count(col("Y")).as("cntY"))
  .sort(col("cntY").desc)
  .show()
+----+----+
|   X|cntY|
+----+----+
|   5|   6|
|   6|   4|
|1234|   4|
|4567|   1|
+----+----+
```